# Make the podcast transcript easier to find

Tags: feature-request, blog, podcast, user-experience

I wanted to take a look at the latest podcast's transcripts - there's a meta question going on about it right now, and I wanted to get up to speed. At the moment, my brain's not quite up to dealing with a half hour long, audio only podcast, so looking at the transcripts felt like a good idea, especially if I needed to quote

[image]

I see a link to play the podcast "organic" to the blog entry. I see episode notes... and... there's no actual link to the transcript.

To *actually* find the transcript, I need to click on share -> more options, *close* the sharing options shade, then click on transcripts on the simplecast page. You can find a gif of the process [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCLmm.gif)

While I appreciate that there are transcripts, it was, as Douglas Adams put it "on display in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying 'Beware of the Leopard.'"

Could we have a direct link, maybe under the episode notes, for easier reference?

Comment: These podcasts ... actually have transcripts? :) Joking aside - yes, the transcript *should* be a direct link. That's (the lack of easy access to it) inconsiderate of the people who actually like reading more than listening to things (and I hope there are still a lot of us around).

Comment: I'm hoping I'm being dense, and there's an easier way :D

Comment: I didn't even find the option you did. I just searched for the podcast on Google to reach the Simplecast-hosted page instead of the blog.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I think it is really [unintuitive to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzHiC.png), tried to search for it myself earlier. I'd never expect so vital an information like a transcript to hide under a "share" button and that only if you click the "more options"...

Comment: “The line between right and wrong can be a crooked one.”
― John Valliant, The Tiger

Comment: @animuson Well- In both cases - it assumes you know there's a transcript.  I *barely* remembered someone mentioning that transcripts were generated automatically, and well, in your case you work here :D. I think most folks on the blog listening to the podcast might not know.

Comment: I can confirm that experience; when I went to check out the podcast in response to the aforementioned Meta question, I opened up the page on the blog, looked for a transcript link, failed to find one, and left after concluding that it did not exist.

Comment: Making the lives of the users easier is not one of SE goals. It's "work hard to find the good stuff" so that we'll become better at it. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like this has been fixed - those who prefer reading over listening rejoice! The all-caps (someone took the issue to heart, huh?) transcript link is now prominently featured right in the middle of the "Episode Notes":

[image: episode notes with highlighted transcript]

Comment: Well - its certainly harder to miss

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I think the vibe of "are you happy now?" is strong in this fix :)

Comment: I'm vocal and I am not afraid to use animated gifs in bug reports. I'm not surprised :D